# Non-ideal inductor effect on inductor current in a quadratic boost converter

Tags: power-electronics, boost

I'm studying a quadratic boost converter and I'm expecting to see in the lab a constant current in the inductors, with a small ripple associated with energy exchanges between the capacitive and inductive elements. 
However, I already know beforehand that in fact, the inductors are not ideal, having a small resistance associated with them. My question is if I should expect to see the currents decrease?

My line of thinking is this. 
In the ideal case we would have input power equal to output power. Now we have input power equal to output power plus the power losses. (NOTE: in the image the output voltage should be in the opposite direction).

$$P_i=P_o+P_{losses}$$

$$V_iI_{LB1}=V_oI_o + r_{LB1}I_{LB1}^2$$

Now because $$I_o=(1-\delta)I_{LB1}$$, we will have:

$$V_iI_{LB1}=V_o(1-\delta)I_{LB1} + r_{LB1}I_{LB1}^2$$

$$V_i=V_o(1-\delta) + r_{LB1}I_{LB1}$$

$$V_i=V_o(1-\delta) + r_{LB1}I_{LB1}$$

$$I_{LB1}=\frac{V_i-V_o(1-\delta)}{r_{LB1}}$$

Therefore, should I immediately conclude that the current decreases? But does that make sense? What about the ripple? I'm not able to realize if it will increase or decrease, but I suppose it will increase? Since it's already an undesirable effect on my converter?
Can someone please clarify me?
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Wow a quadratic boost converter .How does it go if the coils were on the same core?